# Setting a custom /etc/hosts or resolver for one process only in Linux

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, hosts

On Linux, I want that a particular process should resolve host "xyz.com" to IP "10.1.2.3".  That's easy: just add a line to `/etc/hosts`.

However, I only want to do this for *one* process; I want all other processes to resolve "xyz.com" to the DNS.

Is there a way to set a per process resolv.conf or /etc/hosts? I can do this for, e.g., the shared libs or for envariables -- how can I do this for DNS?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have support for network namespaces, iproute2 and iptables, you can accomplish this. Firstly you would want to create a namespace

```
ip netns add NETNS
```

and add your custom host file to the directory `/etc/netns/NETNS/` (you would need to create this directory)

You would then want to create a virtual ethernet pair to connect the newly created namespace with the main namespace, and configure the interfaces

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip link set veth0 up
ip addr add 172.16.1.0/31 dev veth0
ip netns exec NETNS ip link set lo up
ip netns exec NETNS ip link set veth1 up
ip netns exec NETNS ip addr add 172.16.1.1/31 dev veth1
ip netns exec NETNS ip route add default via 172.16.1.0
```

and enable the forwarding of IPv4 packets

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and configure the SNAT

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.1.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

You can then run any command within the network namespace

```
ip netns exec NETNS COMMAND
```

Answer (score 3):

Mount namespace and override file(s) for a process. Kerr's answer is good but may require root. Bubblewrap is a tool to use mount namespace without root.

```
bwrap --dev-bind / / --ro-bind-data {FD} /etc/hosts sh -c "command args"
```

FD is the file descriptor that points to the file containing the content your want to present to the process. (Or, use `--bind` or `--ro-bind` instead of `--ro-bind-data`)

Answer (score 2):

### First:

Ask yourself what you're really trying to accomplish here. This is a very non-standard request that basic tooling isn't prepared to handle. Your basic Linux DNS resolver uses a global configuration (That you already know about in `/etc/resolv.conf`) and you can't really change that per NIC, or domain, or process, or connection.

See if you can design something simpler to achieve the same end result. Future-you will thank present-you

### If you're still reading:

Go back up and read the first section again.

### Still here?

Every fiber of my being is hating itself for what I'm about to suggest.

You can use `iptables` rules that are specific to a process and then redirect DNS traffic accordingly. You could run a separate DNS server on an alternate local port that responds to the domain that you're interested in changing responses for. This should be relatively trivial with `dnsmasq`.

Comment: Where there's a will there's a way ay ? I bet your screws all come with hammer heads.

Comment: I'll have you know that my rivets only get driven with the finest screwdrivers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, systemd does it for the /tmp directory if PrivateTmp is set to yes. But I didn't find details on how to implement it in your own processes for different files. You may want to look at the systemd source for ProvateTmp.

Answer (score 0):

Your question if essentially “how can I make a single command see a different version of a file”

The answer in Linux is a filesystem namespace. You can use the unshare command to launch a new session which has an independent filesystem hierarchy. You can then use mount -o bind /etc/hosts-special /etc/hosts, and then run your command.

This is occasionally very useful (eg have an installer use /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random so it doesn’t starve from entropy without making any changes to the system). To see that in action: https://distracted-it.blogspot.com/2017/03/installer-or-command-that-hangs-use.html

This is something that Docker does nicely for you; perhaps a better way of solving your problem is to put your problem into a container.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, instead of messing with complicated network settings, I would move that process in an LXC container, and inside that container I could edit `/etc/hosts` however I want. LXD/LXC is lightweight and shouldn't cause much overhead.

Comment: LXC containers are just fancy wrappers around network and filesystem namespaces.

Comment: Bread is a fancy wrapper around wheat, water, salt and sourdough...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I override hostname resolution for a single command, without any root access, using the built-in Linux `unshare` command.  I need to use this kind of technique when running FlexLM commands such as `lmutil` because of their crazy network-name requirements:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

# Here, we create the custom 'hosts' file.
# Replace '1.2.3.4' with the IP,
# Replace 'myserver' with the hostname:
echo '1.2.3.4 myserver' >$tmpdir/hosts

unshare -Urm bash <<END
    mount --bind $tmpdir /etc
    lmutil    # REPLACE WITH YOUR COMMAND
END

rm -rf "$tmpdir"
```